# Content Editor Web Part - SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part

I hope this is not an "easy" / "Duh!" kind of answer, because I am driving myself mildly crazy searching for a Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint Online.  This is my first position working with SharePoint Online and in all previous versions that I have worked with, there was the versatile, efficient "Content Editor Web Part" that could be Edited and Added onto SharePoint Sites.

Where can I find / enable Content Editor Web Parts?  Or are they removed from SharePoint Online functionality?

Short GIF of Frustration:

https://gyazo.com/eb5d2aca2c1dfb264579d5dd07e70be0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand your frustration :) but that is how it is for now.

With Modern experience there is not content editor webpart, they are encouraging to use SPFx for same. But PnP has one SPFx react-script editor control which you can use which give same functionality.

Below links would be helpful to get you started.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4

Comment: Well Siddharth, thank you for the bad news haha.  Truly I appreciate your answer and links, I will look into that right away :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe this article will help you out. It espacialy says there is no content Editor Webpart like the ones you know from classic sites : [MS Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc)

I guess what you are looking for are the modern pages itself. You can add richText via the 'Text'-WebPart, Images via 'Image'-WebPart and Files via 'File Viewer'-WebPart and so on. The layouting is done by editing the whole part of the site you are adding content to. So you can make 1 to 3 collums, or 1/3 and 2/3 collums and so on just by editing the next part of the site.

I hope this helps you a bit. 
If not maybe some more Information to your problem would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Content Types are available in SharePoint online.
It might be that Content Type option is not active.

How to allow Custom Scripts 
  -Go to SharePoint admin center and then click on Settings
  -Scroll Down and then allow both options to enable scripting on the site collection 
[image]

It will take 24 hours for this to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: Let me know if this work and please mark as answered if this question helped you.